# How to apply CSS to only immediate children of a certain class

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` and in that `div` I want to create another `div` with a different class and have the inner `div` completely separated from the outer `div` CSS settings.

Like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div><h1> h1 </h1><div>
    <div class="inner">
        <h2> h2 </h2>
    </div>
    <h2> h2 </h2>
</div>
```

```css
.outer h1{ color:blue; }
.outer h2{ color:red; }

.inner { height: 111px; }
```

What I want is to unset the red color from the `h2` in the `"inner" div`

It might seem stupid not to just overweight the color to black here, but what if I have a lot more arguments in the CSS or even if it's dynamic.

**Edit:** I guess it isn't clear, but what I need is actually kind of the opposite of the answers I got so far. I have a main-container div and it has alot of settings in the CSS. Now I want to insert a div into the main-container without it having any of the main-container CSS settings.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
.outer > h2 { color:red; }
```

this way only the direct child of the outer div get this color value, should fix the job.

Comment: ya i guess it isn't clear. but what i need is actually kind of the opposite of that. i have a `main-container div` and it has alot of settings in the `css`. now i want to insert a `div` into the `main-container` without it having any of the `main-container` css settings

Comment: There's a few approaches. One is to specify a `color` just for `.inner h2 { ... }`. This will leave all other h2's within the main-controller div the same, with only the one in inner being different. Another is to give the last h2 a class, and specify a different color for it, and for main-controller to not try to style h2's. This will result in inner's h2 and all other h2's being the same, and the other h2 with a different style. Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/5pvpdfud/

Comment: [There are four different combinators in CSS3:](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)
1. descendant selector (space) : `.outer  h2`: All descendants
2. child selector (>) : `.outer > h2` : Immediate Child
3. adjacent sibling selector (+) : `.outer + h2` : Immediate Sibling from same parent
4. general sibling selector (~) : `.outer ~ h2` : All Sibling from same parent

Answer (score 1):

```
.outer .inner * { color: #000; }
```

sets all elements within the inner container as having the color black.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/bzA29/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is

```
.inner h2 {color: inherit}
```